# Enum data-field in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have an `is_active` column in my database. How do I set the value of an enum data-field to be `(0,1)` in XAMPP. I tried the value field but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp uses MySQL as a backend, so you should look at the [database documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) if you get lost. That being said, the problem is that an enum data type can only be set to particular values, most likely `'active'` and `'inactive'`. You can load up phpmyadmin to see the details of the database configuration, or connect through the command line.